# Optional regex pattern produces no value

Tags: php, xml, regex, pcre

I am having a bit of a problem with some regex I did for a project of mine (please keep in mind that I am a beginner at regex which shows in the follwoing example). I am having a bit of a problem with a piece of xml code from which I am trying to extract certain parts of it using an associated pattern.

```
<banner piclink="pic" urlactive="url_active" urltarget="globaltgt" urllink="globallink" timevar="globaldelay" swf="0" smooth="1" name="name" alt="alternate" />
```

I am using the following regular expression to obtain the piclink, urlactive, urltarget, urllink and timevar using preg_match_all:

```
/piclink=\"(?<pic>.+)\".+urltarget=\"(?<target>.+)\".+urllink=\"(?<url>.*)\".+timevar=\"(?<delay>.*)\"/iU
```

So far so good everything works right however, I am now trying to capture with association  the name and alt tags which are optional as in they don't always appear. I have tried to put them in parenthesis followed by a ? to indicate that they are optional like such:

```
(name=\"(?<name>.*)\")?
```

However the $matches['name'] array is always empty, I do not know where I am messing up but I have tried all sorts of combinations and all of them result in an empty result except for when I put (?: at the end and encapsulate everything from swf= onwards then it does return like 115 results in the array which is not acceptabe as the result is like $matches['name'][X] = result, where x is sometimes 1 other times its at 109 for some reason.

Comment: Do you *need* to use regex?  All your problems could be solved very easily by using SimpleXML instead.

Comment: There is no xml file the code is generated on the fly inside a php. I could modify a lot of the code to store the data as it comes through but right now slapping a regex is less time consuming than rebuilding a whole class just to suit that need. Hmm on second thought I can use simplexml with a string but I wonder if it takes malformed xml code or does it need a complete xml.

Comment: `SimpleXML` can operate on strings as well as files.

Comment: Yes I know but the xml isn't complete at that point that's why I said malformed. It would be broken xml but will it still take it?

Comment: That depends on how broken .. doing `new SimpleXMLElement("<banner from above ... />");` works without error.

Comment: Oh well I'll test it out in the morning, my brain is fuzzy at this hour in this heat. Thanks a lot tandu for giving me the ideea.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I agree that something like `SimpleXML` would be better but if you want to get dirty, you can use lookaheads to try to match with the remaining characters.

```
/piclink=\"(?<pic>.+)\".+urltarget=\"(?<target>.+)\".+urllink=\"(?<url>.*)\".+timevar=\"(?<delay>[^"]*)\"(?=(.*name=\"(?<name>[^"]*)\")?)(?=(.*alt=\"(?<alt>[^"]*)\")?).*/iU
```

Comment: Doesn't work with ungreedy :( name and alt array elements still empty.

Comment: Everything I try with the online regex tool seems to not capture the optional group if it is optional and ungreedy

Comment: Which online tool are you using?

Comment: http://regex.larsolavtorvik.com/ this one, never failed me before. I also ran tests on php mockup files.

Comment: Why does it have to be ungreedy? If it is ungreedy, it will return the shortest match which will obviously not contain the name and alt attributes.